# How to handle java.util.NoSuchElementException: reduce over empty stream akka stream?

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a filter to filter out incorrect items in a stream. In some edge cases this could result in all items being filtered out. When this happens the stream fails with error -
`java.util.NoSuchElementException: reduce over empty stream` on running reduce.

How to handle this case to return a meaningful response?

I have tried supervision like -

```
val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
    case _                      => Supervision.Stop
    case e : NoSuchElementException => Supervision.stop
  }

RunnableGraph.
toMat(Sink.reduce[Int](_ + _)
.withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider)))(Keep.both)
.run()
```

I also tried `recover`, but nothing seems to work.

I need to handle this case to return a meaningful response.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this discussion helps: https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/akka-streams-exception-handling/6557 The main concept is to "treat errors as data", carry them downstream and handle them accordingly. So in your case I guess that the "error" will be the `isEmpty` case.

Answer (score 5):

It may be worth considering using `Sink.fold` instead of `Sink.reduce`:

```scala
val possiblyEmpty = Source(Seq(1, 3, 5)).filter(_ % 2 == 0)
val eventualInt = possiblyEmpty.toMat(Sink.fold[Int](0)(_ + _))(Keep.right).run()
```

If there's no reasonable zero/identity element, you can have something a little more generalized along these lines:

```scala
def reducePossiblyEmpty[T](source: Source[T])(f: (T, T) => T): RunnableGraph[Future[Option[T]]] = {
  val lifted = { (x: Option[T], y: Option[T]) =>
    x.flatMap(a => y.map(f))
  }
  source.map(x => Some(x))
    .concat(Source.single(None))
    .statefulMapConcat[Option[T]] { () =>
      var emptyStream = true
      { x =>
        x match {
          case Some(x) =>
            // element from the given stream
            emptyStream = false
            List(x)

          case None =>
            // given stream completed
            if (emptyStream) {
              List(x)
            } else {
              Nil  // don't emit anything
            }
        }
      }
    }
    .toMat(Sink.reduce[Option[T]](lifted))(Keep.right)
}
```

The returned graph will complete with `None` if there were no elements, or a `Some` of the result of the reduction.

EDIT: you can also just use `orElse` on the `Source`/`Flow`, in lieu of `.concat.statefulMapConcat` in the above:

```scala
def reducePossiblyEmpty[T](source: Source[T])(f: (T, T) => T): RunnableGraph[Future[Option[T]]] = {
  val lifted = { (x: Option[T], y: Option[T]) =>
    x.flatMap(a => y.map(f))
  }

  source.map(x => Some(x))
    .orElse(Source.single(None))
    .toMat(Sink.reduce[Option[T]](lifted))(Keep.right)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just because you're using `Sink.reduce[Int]`, you could add a `Source` that guarantees to have a single element `0` and thus `Sink.reduce[Int]` will work and produce `0` as a result.

Here's an example

```scala
val zero          = Source.single(0)
val possiblyEmpty = Source(List[Int](1, 3, 5)).filter(_ % 2 == 0)
val eventualInt   = zero.merge(possiblyEmpty).toMat(Sink.reduce[Int](_ + _))(Keep.right).run()
```